# Locating Element with Dynamic Text

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

Can anyone help me with creating locator for dymanic text
Here 0 is dynmaic and can be changed for every execution of test script.

```
<a
 title="mytest" href="/abc/test/page1">0  
</a>
```

Here 0 is dynamic and can be changed for different users. I'm using data-driven approach using excel to get input.

Thanks

Comment: I need to click 0 here, but it can be 1 or 100 or 5000 later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(String.format("//a[contains(@title, 'mytest') and text()='{0}']", yourText)));
```

Find the element by title + your dynamic text passed to the string.Format method.

Comment: Thanks Anton,I will try this as well. Can you please explain text() = '%1$s'?

Comment: this should be {0} placeholder for the format method. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'mytest')]"));
```

Comment: Thanks peetya for your quick response, but it didnt work for me. I used .//*[@id='main']/div/div/form[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/a and it worked.